# How to use multiple where in multiple table in laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to get the same result by using laravel eloquent.

My database structure is-

- `user` table: id, email, password, user_role, subusertype
- `profile` table: id, firstname, lastname, phone, user_id, company_id, branch_id
- `company` table: id, name
- `branch` table: id, address, contact

I need to fetch user profiles by branch.id where user.subusertype is "Employee".

I have this query builder code now I need to make it with laravel eloquent.

```
            $employeedata=DB::table('branch')
                     ->join('profile','profile.branch_id',"=",'branch.id')
                     ->join('user','profile.user_id','=','user.id')
                     ->join('company','profile.company_id','=','company.id')
             ->select('profile.*','user.email','user.subusertype','company.name','branch.address')
                    ->where('branch.id',$branch_id)
                    ->where('user.subusertype',"Employee")
                    ->get();
```

I had tried this code but it returns all profiles those subusertype is not "Employee" giving user object null value.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Are you getting any errors? It's impossible for us to help you without more information or what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to get the same result by using laravel eloquent.

my database structure is-
user table-id,email,password,user_role,subusertype.
profile table-id,firstname,lastname,phone,user_id,company_id,branch_id.
company table-id,name.
branch table-id,address,contact.

now i need to fetch user profiles by branch where their subusertype is "Employee"

Comment: i had tried this code but it returns all profiles those subusertype is not "Employee" giving user object null value. $employeedata=Branch::with(['profile'=>function($query){
            $query->with(['user'=>function($qry){
                $qry->where('subusertype','Employee')->get();
            },'branch','company'])->get();
        }])->find($branch_id);

Answer (score 0):

Use can use as :

```
$employeedata=Branch::select('profile.*','user.email','user.subusertype','company.name','branch.address')
                     ->join('profile','profile.branch_id',"=",'branch.id')
                     ->join('user','profile.user_id','=','user.id')
                     ->join('company','profile.company_id','=','company.id')
                     ->where('branch.id',$branch_id)
                     ->where('user.subusertype',"Employee")
                     ->get();
```

Instead of using joins you can use laravel `Eloquent: Relationships`. To know about laravel relationship [click here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships)